# Java LED programming

Tags: java, led

Just wondering if there are any Java API's that enable you to control the LED's found on desktop/laptop cases?

Or, if not, is it at all possible?

Comment: Depends on how the LED is exposed to userspace.  It's a fair bit easier to [do it with an Arduino board, though.](http://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/BlinkingLED)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're talking about the LEDs on the front that indicates the power state and HDD busy state, I'm afraid there's no way to play with them. AFAIK they are directly controlled by the controllers in the mainboard, and are not exposed to any software above BIOS.

If you want to plug in custom set of LEDs to your machine and control them with Java, then you can connect them to a serial or parallel port and use Java `native` methods (which essentially talk to C or C++ code) to control them. AFAIK, this is because the JVM doesn't have direct APIs to talk to underlying hardware. This can become quite tricky as Windows Vista and later **requires** a kernel mode driver to communicate with ports and are blocked for all user-mode software. So you C++ code should talk to kernel mode drivers.

Another way is to disconnect your LEDs from the PC and communicate via a custom protocol over WiFi or Bluetooth. As mentioned by @Makoto,  you can use arduino or a similar board and communicate via either a wireless or a wired technology.

Comment: Ahh thanks Madushan. Interesting stuff about the wireless Arduino. 
I did a little search on Goolge about the desktop/laptops LED's and found very little. So, I guess to confirm what your saying, it's probably not possible.

Comment: You may not be able to debug the Arduino code wirelessly. But I think the arduino supports hooking up bluetooth adapters and WiFi antennas and stuff. You'll have to make up a protocol through those to communicate with the code running on your PC.

Comment: I actually have a Beagleboard XM thats not getting much use, and a spair bluetooth adapter.  has Java installed on it.

Comment: Sorry, I've never even remotely done it. :) I only know that it's possible. Honestly, this is like the second time ever, I heard about beagleboard :)

Comment: Yeah those guys are crazy. One guy tried to make a HAM radio station out of one. Others make home surveillance systems. It can run a range of operating systems like angstrom linux and android. I bought one in the hope I could increase the processing power of an old laptop. I thought it was possible - It wasn't :( But, in all honesty the liquidware BB is one of the coolest projects Ive ever seen. Have a look at one: http://2.bp.blogspot.com/_pGsJFsc5Buc/TLv8RaUrCYI/AAAAAAAAA0c/iAnTlNwoWp0/s1600/Android+BeagleBoard+Gadget+Liquidware+Front+Menu.jpg